# Populate DataGridView Column With a Double forcing to 2 Decimal Places, with Sort

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, formatting

Sorry for the weird title but I didn't know how to phrase it any better.

I'm trying to populate a column on my DataGridView with a number that has 2 decimal places.

To do this I'm using

```
Dim _Size as Double = 1.2345
DataGridView1.Item(0, 0).Value = Format(_Size, "0.00")
```

This populates the data correctly, but when sorting by this column, it treats the item as a string.

I found on the net, that if you convert the data being entered to a number type (double, integer etc..), it will then sort it like a number instead of a string.
This works brilliantly, but any values that are integers with 2 decimal places (i.e. 1.00) are changed to 0 decimal places.

So, if I had the following values

```
1.2345
2.2345
3.2345
4.2345
5.0011
```

and I formatted as 2 decimal places they would then become

```
1.23
2.23
3.23
4.23
5.00
```

if I then converted them back to doubles they then become

```
1.23
2.23
3.23
4.23
5
```

Is there any way of populating a DataGridView with these values formatted as 2 decimal places but keeping the double type so that the column sorts correctly?

I hope I've explained this clearly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The legacy VB Format function returns a string, which accounts for the conversion.  When that happens the other decimals are lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *converting* your values to string by using the legacy VB Format function:

```
Function Format(Expression As Object, Optional Style As String = "") As String
```

When it is converted, the other decimals are lost.  Use the `Format` Property of the `DefaultCellStyle` for that column to specify the number of decimal places you want (`N2` for 2 decimals).  Unlike VB's `Format`, this acts like a "DisplayAs" without altering the value or changing the Type.

- In the Properties pane, select `Columns` to start the column editor
- Pick the column
- Click the `DefaultCellStyle` property
- For `Format`, click the `...` button to select from a list.  `Numeric` and `2 Decimals` results in `N2`

If you store a numeric values in that column, only 2 decimal places will display, but the actual/original value will still be available and sorting will using the numeric value rather than a text sort.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I would have spent ages trying to get this to work and probably ended up just settling with an option I wasn't happy with. Thank you again!